# Concatenating javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, concatenation, dry

If I have 300 functions like this:

```
function name1() {
  alert("1");
}

function name2() {
  alert("2");
}

function name3() {
  alert("3");
}
```

Etc all the way to 300, how could I concatenate these all into one function because they are so similar even though each one does have slight differences?

**UPDATE**:

Sorry, I used example functions because I didn't think it would matter to put my long code in the question, but I think it does matter now, here are the real functions:

```
function event() {
    //paths
    var path = document.querySelector('#container #path'); 
    var length = path.getTotalLength(); 
    console.log(path.getTotalLength()); 
    // Clear any previous transition
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    // Set up the starting positions
    path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
    // picks up the starting position before animating
    path.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 0.4s linear';
    // Go!
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

    document.getElementById("container").style.visibility = "visible";
};

function event2() {
    //paths
    var path2 = document.querySelector('#container2 #path_2');
    var length = path2.getTotalLength();
    console.log(path2.getTotalLength());
    // Clear any previous transition
    path2.style.transition = path2.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    // Set up the starting positions
    path2.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path2.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
    // picks up the starting position before animating
    path2.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition
    path2.style.transition = path2.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 0.45s linear';
    // Go!
    path2.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

    document.getElementById("container2").style.visibility = "visible";
};

function event3() {
    //paths
    var path3 = document.querySelector('#container3 #path_3');
    var length = path3.getTotalLength();
    console.log(path3.getTotalLength());
    // Clear any previous transition
    path3.style.transition = path3.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    // Set up the starting positions
    path3.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path3.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
    // picks up the starting position before animating
    path3.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition
    path3.style.transition = path3.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 0.4s linear';
    // Go!
    path3.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

    document.getElementById("container3").style.visibility = "visible";
};


window.setTimeout(function() {
    event();
}, 1);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    event2();
}, 550);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    event3();
}, 1100);
```

So I would have to make changes to them, but the majority of it is the same, so how would I do it given this code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `function name( nr ) { alert( nr ); }`?

Comment: if you really need to make individual functions, which I'm assuming you don't, you could use eval() in a loop, but I would use a parameter instead

Comment: Are these the actual functions that you are using?

Comment: @isherwood what does that matter?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, seeing as the comment was phrased as a question.

Comment: also comments can be upvoted...

Comment: Without knowing exactly what "each one does have slight differences" is exactly, it is hard to tell you HOW to do it. In your example it looks like it is just a different string, but I have a feeling it is a little more complicated than that.

Comment: @isherwood To be honest I didn't think, that the solution might be that simple. Was more to tease OP for more info.

Comment: K I updated it Sirko

Answer (score 2):

Create a function with a param :

```
function name(myNumber) {
  alert(myNumber);
}
name(1);
name(2);
name(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop and a parameter

```
function name(x) {
    alert(x);
}

for (var i = 1; i <=300; i++) {
    name(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a parameter with your function:

```
function name(number) {
  alert(number);
}
```

So you could call it with `name(1)`, `name(2)`, `name(3)`, etc.

If you wanted to do this for every number from 1 to 300, you would use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
  name(i);
}
```

If you want to start at 1, just change `var i = 0` to `var i = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling them at some point, right? So why not just make this function:

```
function name(i) {
  alert(i);
}
```

And call it with `name(1)`, `name(2)`, `name(3)`, etc